# Release new version of unlocked package

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, second-generation-packaging

I have a sfdx-project.json for my unlocked package. Version 1.0.0-11 was promoted.

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
       {
           "path": "force-app",
           "default": true,
           "package": "PACKAGE_NAME",
           "versionName": "Version 1.0",
           "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT",
           "features": "MultiCurrency"
       }
   ],
   "namespace": "",
   "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
   "sourceApiVersion": "48.0",
   "packageAliases": {
       "PACKAGE_NAME": "0HoXXX",
       "PACKAGE_NAME@1.0.0-11": "04tXXX"
   }
}
```

I want to release new version 1.0.1. I changed the following rows in the file:

- "versionName": "Version 1.0" to "versionName": "Version 1.0.1"
- "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT" to "versionNumber": "1.0.1.NEXT"

After I try to create new package version the system creates new 1.0.0-12 instead of 1.0.1-1. Also it removes all my changes back for versionName and versionNumber.

What is the right way to release new version?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a bug? You should be able to specify the new starting point by specifying an explicit version number:

```
"versionNumber": "1.0.1.0",
```

Once you create this version, you should be able to change the version to 1.0.1.NEXT as you'd expect.

Comment: very strange. Maybe my command is wrong. sfdx force:package:version:create -p PACKAGE_NAME -d force-app -k your_password --wait 10 -v DevHub

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug. Reboot helped as always :(